# In telerik reporting, how to set web service datasource url from appsettings.json?

Tags: telerik-reporting

I am using .net core 3.1 rest api and I want to set telerik report web service data source url from appsettings.json

Is it possible? I have searched many of their official documents but their document is not clear enough to understand. Thank you.

Comment: Their documentation is very poor and unreliable.

Comment: Does this help? https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/knowledge-base/how-to-customize-web-service-data-source-url https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/knowledge-base/how-to-retrieve-the-connection-strings-from-environment-variables

Comment: Can you provide an example on how to configure it. The documentation didn't mentioned a example properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is tricky. In the data source url, use the variable like @variableName
In next wizard, You will see @variableName will be showing in the request parameters tab. Put the value there, it will work.
Though it is not a very user friendly approach from telerik, because the tab says it's for request parameters only, I would recommend  telerik to re design this tab and make it more user friendly. Putting non http request variables inside request parameter tab is very confusing and non standard practice.

[image]
[image]

Along with that, you can have more control, during the runtime, you can set the parameter from your c# code and in this way you will be able to pass your values from runtime